Evaluating scikit-learn metrics in Keras
I want to evaluate 3 metrics in a Keras model using scikit-learn metrics like this:
from sklearn.metrics import coverage_error
def coverage(Y_train, y_score):
    err = coverage_error(Y_train.numpy(), y_score.numpy())
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(err)

I encounter the error:

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I run the code in eager mode to solve the error:
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()

however by runing in eager mode and debugging mode, the execution is 30 times slower and it does not utilize GPU.
Furthermore here there is an explanation about using scikit-learn metrics in keras, however it does not return the metric result in every epoch.
Can you help me to figure out how to get the scikit-learn metric report in every epoch and utilizng GPU at the same time.

This happens in the older version of TensorFlow, upgrade to newer versions, and it should work fine. However in the latest version, eager run is true by default.
In that case, you could explicitly typecast to a numpy array and then return a tensor.
err = coverage_error(tf.make_ndarray(Y_train),tf.make_ndarray(y_score))


I am getting following error when using tf.make_ndarray: 'AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape''
